# Tab completion error: bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, files, deleted-files

I am absolutely new to Linux.

I downloaded 50GB of data on the server disk via `SSH`.

Then I deleted them using *midnight commander*.

Now, the tab-completion doesn't work, and it is giving me the following error:

```
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

find out what's taking so much space (in your home folder)

```
find /home/$USER -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d   | xargs du -sm | sort -n
(...)
6517    /home/jaroslav/Data
7697    /home/jaroslav/tmp
19636   /home/jaroslav/src
```

It could also be that /tmp is full (where the temporary file is being created). Use df to find out:

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p9               421G  354G   63G  85% /
/dev/nvme0n1p9               421G  354G   63G  85% /home
(...)
```

If /tmp or / shows up as 100% in use, then use `du` to find what you can remove...

Comment: By default, Bash creates temporary files in `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` if they're writable (unless the `TMPDIR` environment variable is set, in which case it checks that first). Only after that it uses the current directory, so it's a bit unlikely it'd try to create the temp file in `$HOME`.